# Отправка формы c методом post одновременно на сайт ,к которому я не причастен, и в личный обработчик HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, post, form, action

Итак, есть форма, имя/пароль/телефон/чтоугодно.  При отправке формы срабатывает action который изначально отправляет форму на сайт. Потребовалось сделать так, чтоб эта форма полностью копировалась нам же. Т.е. чтоб она улетела к другим ребятам и одновременно обработалась у нас. Как сделать не прикручивая JS?
Вот форма

```
   <form method="POST" action=" здесь ссылка на обработчик с которым у нас нет связи и возможности изменить" >
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="2name" value="" placeholder="2Name"/>
<button>Next</button> 
    </form>
```

Как отправить эту форму на обработчик у меня, при этом отправив еще и по ссылке? Я новичок, заранее спасибо.

В попытках принять форму написал обработчик, но отправить ее сразу и туда, и к себе не додумался как...

```
if($_POST){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$2name = $_POST['2name'];

$file = "orders.txt";
$fam = "Имя: $name \n Фамилия: $2name \n";
$save_fam = fopen($file, 'a+');
fwrite($save_fam, $fam);
fclose($save_fam);
}
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо, сначала отправлять данные на свой обработчик, а потом, посредством, например, `curl` отправлять эти данные на необходимый вам url, подробнее про `curl` можно прочитать тут https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php